# Android SQL query of a not existing row

Tags: android, sql, database, insert

I got a little problem with my SQLite database in my app.
My goal is to insert a row into my database if it's not exist, otherwise to update the row.

How can I check if the row with the given condition exists?

I tried:

```
Cursor cursor = dbAdapter.query(dbName, null, "xcoord="+xcoord+" AND ycoord="+ycoord+" AND mac='"+mac+"'"+" AND ssid='"+ssid+"'", null, null, null, null);
cursor.isNull(cursor.getColumnIndex("ssid"));
```

and then to check if the cursor is null? But so I got this SQLException:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
>
> at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)

Thanks for help.

Comment: what is the exception that you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before working with a cursor in anyway I always do an `if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())`

If that evaluates to false, you either don't have a table, or you don't have a record.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the word `EXISTS` from your query.  If you get any rows back, you know the thing is in there.

The `EXISTS` clause takes a row set as the operand (like a sub-select or join) and evaluates as true or false based on whether or not anything is there.

It's maybe not the best way to handle this, but I usually just attempt the `INSERT`, and if I get an exception, I do an `UPDATE`.